# Bundling css and js in .Net core 3 and blazor

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a .net core 3 application with blazor. I have a 2 folders of js and css files that I want to bundle and minify. Can someone please suggest a good library for bundling and minification? Preferably part of dotnet otherwise a third party library is fine.

Thank you

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/bundling-and-minification?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using [Bundler & Minifier](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.BundlerMinifier) extension with visual studio. you can create multiple bundle file as per your requirement. below is my webiste bundle file

```
[{
"outputFileName": "wwwroot/css/bundle.min.css",
"inputFiles": [
  "wwwroot/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
  "wwwroot/lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
  "wwwroot/lib/sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.min.css",
  "wwwroot/css/style.css"
],
"minify": {
  "enabled": true,
  "renameLocals": true
}
  },
  {
"outputFileName": "wwwroot/js/bundle.min.js",
"inputFiles": [
  "wwwroot/js/location.js",
  "wwwroot/js/login.js",
  "wwwroot/js/ManageClassified.js",
  "wwwroot/js/createClassified.js",
  "wwwroot/js/searchClassifield.js"
],
"minify": {
  "enabled": true,
  "renameLocals": true
}
  }]
```